# How can I limit Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, parallel.foreach

I have a Parallel.ForEach() async loop with which I download some webpages. My bandwidth is limited so I can download only x pages per time but Parallel.ForEach executes whole list of desired webpages.

Is there a way to limit thread number or any other limiter while running Parallel.ForEach?

Demo code:

```
Parallel.ForEach(listOfWebpages, webpage => {
  Download(webpage);
});
```

The real task has nothing to do with webpages, so creative web crawling solutions won't help.

Comment: @jKlaus If the list isn't modified e.g. it's just a set of URLs, I can't really see the issue?

Comment: @Shiv, given enough time you will...  Count your number of executions and compare it to the count of the list.

Comment: @jKlaus What are you saying will go wrong?

Comment: @Shiv, execute this a few times.. https://dotnetfiddle.net/maKiI5

Comment: @jKlaus you are modifying a non-threadsafe element (the integer). I would expect it to not work in that scenario. The OP on the other hand is not modifying anything that needs to be threadsafe.

Comment: @Shiv, Are you positive?  I haven't seen the source code for Download().

Comment: @jKlaus Yes Download() has no reference to listOfWebpages

Comment: @jKlaus Here is an example of Parallel.ForEach that sets the count correctly > https://dotnetfiddle.net/moqP2C. MSDN Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997393(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @jKlaus - so... you should delete your comments / this whole chain is misleading... what you initially pointed out is not actually a problem with the above code, since he's passing the single current loop item to the method. There's no sharing of variables between threads/loop-executions.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` is not suitable for throttling I/O operations. Look at this question for proper solutions: [How to limit the amount of concurrent async I/O operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations)

Answer (score 702, accepted):

You can specify a `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` in a `ParallelOptions` parameter:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    listOfWebpages,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
    webpage => { Download(webpage); }
);
```

MSDN: [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783747.aspx)

MSDN: [ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx)

Comment: It may not apply to this particular case but I figured I'd throw it out in case anyone wonders across this and finds it useful.

Here I am utilizing 75% (rounded up) of the processor count.

`var opts = new ParallelOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((Environment.ProcessorCount * 0.75) * 1.0))
            };`

Comment: Just to save anyone else having to look it up in the documentation, passing a value of `-1` is the same as not specifying it at all: _"If [the value] is -1, there is no limit on the number of concurrently running operations"_

Comment: It's not clear to me from documentation - does setting MaxDegreeOfParallelism to 4 (for instance) mean there'll be 4 threads each running 1/4th of the loop iterations (one round of 4 threads dispatched), or does each thread still do one loop iteration and we're just limiting how many run in parallel?

Comment: To be clear cores and threads are not the same thing.  Depending on the CPU, there are a different number of threads per core, usually 2 per core.  For example, if you have a 4 core CPU with 2 threads per core, then you have a max of 8 threads.  To adjust 
@jKlaus comment `var opts = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((Environment.ProcessorCount * 0.75) * 2.0)) };`.  Link to threads vs cores -  https://askubuntu.com/questions/668538/cores-vs-threads-how-many-threads-should-i-run-on-this-machine

Comment: @Agrejus I think Environment.ProcessorCount is the number of logical processors on the machine, not the cores; as you described 4 cores with, typically 2 threads, would be 8 threads/logical processors max. On such a device, Environment.ProcessCount would be 8.

In the jKlaus example, he is accurately getting the 75% of max thread count (6 of 8), with your example, you end up with 150% of max thread count (12 of 8).

Answer (score 62):

You can use ParallelOptions and set MaxDegreeOfParallelism to limit the number of concurrent threads:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    listOfwebpages, 
    new ParallelOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism=2}, 
    webpage => {Download(webpage);});
```

Answer (score 25):

Use another overload of `Parallel.Foreach` that takes a [`ParallelOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.aspx) instance, and set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to limit how many instances execute in parallel.

Answer (score 17):

And for the VB.net users (syntax is weird and difficult to find)...

```
Parallel.ForEach(listOfWebpages, New ParallelOptions() With {.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8}, Sub(webpage)
......end sub)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the more dynamic and realistic approach would be to limit it by the processor count, so on each system it would function properly:

```cs
var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount };
Parallel.ForEach(myList, options, iter => { });
```

perhpas yu would multiply `Environment.ProcessorCount` or divide it to put or take more pressure from the CPU