# Rx.NET - Downloading two files at a time

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm trying to download a list of files (using reactive extensions), maintaining maximum TWO parallel downloads at a time.

So far I didn't come across a working sample.

The closest thing so far is :

[How can I limit Parallel.ForEach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290498/how-can-i-limit-parallel-foreach)

But I want to do the same that via Rx.net
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Rx because list is dynamic?

Comment: Not necessarily. It'd be list of n URLs or Action (sync methods i.e the download activity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Observable.Merge` takes a `maxConcurrent` argument which lets you limit how many parallel subscriptions are maintained.  So you can do something like this:

```
public class DownloadResult { /*...*/ }

public Task<DownloadResult> DownloadFileAsync(string path) { /*...*/ }


public IObservable<DownloadResult> DownloadFiles(int maxConcurrent, string[] paths)
{
    return paths
        .Select(path => Observable.FromAsync(() => DownloadFileAsync(path)))
        .Merge(maxConcurrent: maxConcurrent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ran your script with linqpad but it won't yield the desired result. Can you please comment on this : http://pastebin.com/5WBQXQv5

Comment: yes your `DownloadAsync` isnt really async.  Never `new` a Task.  Use `Task.Run` instead.  Or declare your method `async` and get rid of the Task construction and use `await Task.Delay(1000);` instead of `Sleep`