# Httpclient tpl parallel multiple request fastest way

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, httpclient

I want to download webPages content of url list (10 000 urls).

1. Is httpCLient the fastest and cleanest way (instead httpwebrequest, or webclient)?
2. If I want to be fast, Is TPL the best way ?

I'm looking for something like, but really fast and clean (10 000 request) ?

```
public List<string> GetContentListOfUrlList(List<Uri> uriList, int maxSimultaneousRequest)
    {
        //requesting url by the fastest way

    }
```

I hope is better like this ;)

EDIT 2 :
According to noseratio [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492383/throttling-asynchronous-tasks/22493662#22493662)
**Is the best solution ?**

```
public async Task<List<string>> DownloadAsync(List<Uri> urls, int maxDownloads)
    {
        var concurrentQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

        using (var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxDownloads))
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var tasks = urls.Select(async (url) =>
            {
                await semaphore.WaitAsync();
                try
                {
                    var data = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
                    concurrentQueue.Enqueue(data);
                }
                finally
                {
                    semaphore.Release();
                }
            });

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
        }
        return concurrentQueue.ToList();
    }
```

Questions

1. configureAwait? Should I use

   var data = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);

var data = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

2. ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit? Should I change this property as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I limit Parallel.ForEach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290498/how-can-i-limit-parallel-foreach)

Comment: Please clarify you requestion, perhaps with a code example. Currently, i have no clue what you *actually* want to do.

Comment: @iVision I edited my question to be clearer

Comment: Don't use TPL for naturally async I/O-bound tasks, rather use async APIs. E.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22493662/1768303

Comment: @Noseratio `async/await` is more-or-less syntactic sugar over TPL. In this particular case, the aim is to fire many requests concurrently, not await them one by one. At best, after calling `GetStringAsync` 1000 times, you get to `await Task.WhenAll(theCalls)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, feel free to click the link I posted to see what I meant. It doesn't do it one by one. It's about using *a naturally async, non-blocking API* like `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` - as opposed to calling a blocking API like `WebClient.DownloadString` in parallel with `Parallel.ForEach`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos *async/await is more-or-less syntactic sugar over TPL* Not really. `async-await` isn't bound to the TPL at all, and has nothing to do with parallalism.

Comment: @Julian50 What have you tried so far? You don't simply request for code, you need to show an attempt to begin with.

Comment: @Julian50, to address your edit, it's just one way of doing that. You could also use TPL Dataflow as [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22492731/1768303) suggests. Or, you could also use Reactive Extensions. We can't tell you what's best for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a *ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism* Property which specifies the maximum number of concurrent operations:

```
Parallel.ForEach(list, 
        new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallism = 4 }, 
        DownloadPage);
```

Reference: [MaxDegreeOfParallism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)