# Handling Parallel Jobs/Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, spinlock, interlocked-increment

I'm trying to refactoring my project and now I'm trying to research for best ways to increase the application's performance.

**Question 1. SpinLock vs Interlocked**

To creating a counter, which way has better performance.

```
Interlocked.increament(ref counter)
```

Or

```
SpinLock _spinlock = new SpinLock()
bool lockTaken = false;
try
{
    _spinlock.Enter(ref lockTaken);
    counter = counter + 1;                
}
finally
 { 
     if (lockTaken) _spinlock.Exit(false);
 }
```

And if we need to increment another counter, like `counter2`, should we declare another `SpinLock` object? or its enough to use another `boolean` object?

**Question 2. Handling nested tasks or better replacement**

In this current version of my application, I used tasks, adding each new task to an array and then used `Task.WaitAll()`

After a lot of research I just figured out that using `Parallel.ForEach` has better performance, But how can I control the number of current threads? I know I can specify a `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` in a `ParallelOptions` parameter, but the problem is here, every time `crawl(url)` method runs, It just create another limited number of threads, I mean if I set `MaxDegree` to 10, every time `crawl(url)` runs, another +10 will created, am I right?, so how can I prevent this? should I use semaphore and threads instead of Parallel? Or there is a better way?

```
public void Start() {
    Parallel.Invoke(() => { crawl(url) } );
}


crawl(string url) {
    var response =  getresponse(url);
    Parallel.foreach(response.links, ParallelOption, link => {
        crawl(link);
    });
}
```

**Question 3. Notify when all Jobs (and nested jobs) finished.**

And my last question is how can I understand when all my jobs has finished?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Httpclient tpl parallel multiple request fastest way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165332/httpclient-tpl-parallel-multiple-request-fastest-way)

Comment: If you are often downloading multiple urls from the same domain, you likely also want to bump up the value of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit(v=vs.110).aspx .

Comment: Ad 1) Why do you think that a specialized method to increment a value in a thread-safe manner is (relevantly) less performant compared to a complex construct of acquiring a lock, optionally waiting for the lock to be free, incrementing the value and releasing the lock?

Comment: @ckuri according to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/how-to-use-spinlock-for-low-level-synchronization)

Comment: Ad 2) I don’t see the point in wrapping Parallel.ForEach inside a Parallel.Invoke. Parallel.Invoke executes multiple actions in parallel, but you only have one action `crawl`. Even if there would be multiple actions, as the Parallel class takes threads from the threadpool you would just starve the threadpool and not gain any benefit or even hurt your performance. Ad 3) You know all your jobs finished when Parallel.ForEach ends.

Comment: @Mahdi The MSDN is comparing `SpinLock` to `lock` - Interlocked is much more efficient than either.

Comment: Your `crawl` method is going to die a horrible recursive death

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. [It should focus on one problem only.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

Answer (score 2):

There a is a lot of misconceptions here, I'll point out just a few.

> To creating a counter, which way has better performance.

They both do, depending on your **exact** situation

> After a lot of research I just figured out that using Parallel.ForEach
>   has better performance

This is also very suspect, and actually just wrong. Once again it depends on what you want to do.

> I know I can specify a MaxDegreeOfParallelism in a ParallelOptions
>   parameter, but the problem is here, every time crawl(url) method runs, It just create another limited number of threads

Once again this is wrong, this is your own implementation detail, and depends on how you do it. also *TPL* `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is only a suggestion, it will only do what it thinks heuristically is best for you.

> should I use semaphore and threads instead of Parallel? Or there is a
>   better way?

The answer is a resounding yes.

---

OK, let's have a look at what you are doing. You say you are making a crawler. A crawler, accesses the internet, each time you access the internet or a network resource or the file system you are (said simplistically) waiting around for an IO completion port callbacks. This is what's knows as an *IO workload*.

With *IO Bound* tasks we don't want to tie up the thread pool with threads waiting for *IO completion ports*. It's inefficient, you are using up valuable resources waiting for callback on threads that are effectively paused.

So for *IO bound work*, we don't want to spin up new tasks, and we don't want to use *Parallel ForEach* to wait around using up threads waiting for events to happen. The most appropriate modern pattern for *IO bound tasks* is the `async` and `await` pattern.

For CPU bound work (if you want to use as much CPU as you can) smash the thread pool, use *TPL Parallel* or as many tasks that is effective.

The `async` and `await` pattern works well with completion ports, because instead of waiting around idly for a callback it will give the threads back and allow them to be reused.

...

However what I suggest is using another approach, where you can take advantage of `async` and `await` and also control degrees of parallelisation. This enables you to be good to your thread pool, not using up resources waiting for callbacks, and allowing IO to be IO. I give you `TPL DataFlow` `ActionBlock` and `TransformManyBlocks`

---

This subject is a little above a simple working example, but I can assure you its an appropriate path for what you are doing. What I suggest is you have a look at the following links.

- *Stephen Cleary* [There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)
- *Stephen Cleary* [Introduction to Dataflow](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/09/introduction-to-dataflow-part-1.html)
- *Msdn Blogs* [Parallel Programming with .NET](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/tag/dataflow/)
- *Stephen Toub* [Going Deep Stephen Toub: Inside TPL Dataflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFMv_nFIfvk), In this he even talks about crawler examples.
- *Some random blog on dataflow and crawlers* [Tpl Dataflow walkthrough – Part 5](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/bnaya/2012/01/28/tpl-dataflow-walkthrough-part-5/)

In Summary, there are many ways to do what you want to do, and there are many technologies. But the main thing is you have some very skewed ideas about parallel programming. You need to hit the books, hit the blogs, and start getting some really solid design principles from the ground up, and stop trying to figure this all out for your self by nit picking small bits of information.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest looking at Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this. You can write your `Crawl` function like this:

```
public IObservable<Response> Crawl(string url)
{
    return
        from r in Observable.Start(() => GetResponse(url))
        from l in r.Links.ToObservable()
        from r2 in Crawl(l).StartWith(r)
        select r2;
}
```

Then to call it try this:

```
IObservable<Response> crawls = Crawl("www.microsoft.com");

IDisposable subscription =
    crawls
        .Subscribe(
            r => { /* process each response as it arrives */ },
            () => { /* All crawls complete */ });
```

Done. It handles all the threading for you. Just NuGet "System.Reactive".