# How can I use Parallel foreach for my requirement where I want to break list of 10k customers in to 4 batches and process each queue

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

```
public void ReprocessComms()
{
    List<Customer> custList = new List<Customer>();
    custList.ForEach(t => _repo.Process(t));
}

public void Process(Customer obj)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SendComms(obj));
}
```

Currently I'm using this code, but I want to divide it into 4 batches and each batch should run in parallel. Each batch calls `SendComms` for 2500 customers.

Comment: Do you care about using EXACTLY 4 batches?

Comment: i dont want too many threads , hence said 4-5 .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I limit Parallel.ForEach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290498/how-can-i-limit-parallel-foreach)

Comment: And what did you try? What about simply dividing the list into 4 batches and then calling Parallel.ForEach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the one hand, you can limit the number of tasks that is run in parallel by using [ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Parallel.ForEach(custList, 
    new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, 
    Process);
```

If you need the batches for another reason, you can split your customers in groups like this:

```
var groups = from custWithIndex in items.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Customer = x }) 
        group custWithIndex by custWithIndex.Index % 4 into grp 
        select new { GroupKey = grp.Key, Customers = grp.Select(y => y.Customer)};
```

On the other hand, calling Parallel.ForEach on the groups is a bit more complicated as in the previous approach, so MaxDegreeOfParallelism should be the better choice if the main goal is to limit the number of tasks that are run in parallel:

```
Parallel.ForEach(groups, group => {
    foreach(var cust in group.Customers)
        Process(cust);
    });
```

Comment: I have added the 
 
' public void ReprocessComms()
{
    List<Customer> custList = new List<Customer>();
    // custList.ForEach(t => _repo.Process(t));
 
 Parallel.ForEach(custList, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, (obj) =>
                {
                    _repo.SendComms(obj);

                });
}'

Answer (score -1):

```
I thought we can use linq take() and skip()  methods. But we need to specify the starting and ending index. 

Total 10000,
List<Customerlist>CustomerlistBatch=new List<customerlist>();
Dictionary<int,int> StartEnd=new Dictionary<int,int>();
0  = > 0-2500
1  = > 2500-5000
2  = > 5000-7500
3  = > 7500-10000

For each item as StartEnd
{
CustomerlistBatch.Add(customerlist.take(item.key).skip(item.value).Select(x=>x).tolist());

}
```

Comment: i dont want to resctict like 2500 for each batch. total number of customers can change as it comes from UI. text box for number of customers. person using the UI can input 5k or 10k or 20k in the UI