# Processing large number of tasks concurrently and asynchronously

Tags: c#

I would like to process a list of 50,000 urls through a web service, The provider of this service allows 5 connections per second.

I need to process these urls in parallel with adherence to provider's rules.

This is my current code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    process_urls().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

}
public static async Task process_urls()
{
    // let's say there is a list of 50,000+ URLs
    var urls = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("urls.txt");

    var allTasks = new List<Task>();
    var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: 5);

    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
        await throttler.WaitAsync();

        allTasks.Add(
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Starting {0}", url));
                    var client = new HttpClient();
                    var xml = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                    //do some processing on xml output
                    client.Dispose();
                }
                finally
                {
                    throttler.Release();
                }
            }));
    }   
    await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);   
}
```

Instead of `var client = new HttpClient();` I will create a new object of the target web service but this is just to make the code generic.

Is this the correct approach to handle and process a huge list of connections? and is there anyway I can limit the number of established connections per second to 5 as the current implementation will not consider any timeframe?

Thanks

Comment: You could use Parallel.ForEach loop and limit its degree of parallelism as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9290531/6170142).

Answer (score 2):

Reading values from web service is IO operation which can be done asynchronously without multithreading.
Threads do nothing - only waiting for response in this case. So using parallel is just wasting of resources.

```
public static async Task process_urls()
{
    var urls = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("urls.txt");

    var allTasks = new List<Task>();
    var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: 5);

    foreach (var urlGroup in SplitToGroupsOfFive(urls))
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach(var url in urlGroup)
        {
            var task = ProcessUrl(url);
            tasks.Add(task);
        }
        // This delay will sure that next 5 urls will be used only after 1 seconds
        tasks.Add(Task.Delay(1000));

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }
}

private async Task ProcessUrl(string url)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var xml = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        //do some processing on xml output
    }
}

private IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> SplitToGroupsOfFive(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    var const GROUP_SIZE = 5;
    var string[] group = null;
    var int count = 0;

    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
        if (group == null)
            group = new string[GROUP_SIZE];

        group[count] = url;
        count++;

        if (count < GROUP_SIZE) 
            continue;

        yield return group;

        group = null;
        count = 0;
    }

    if (group != null && group.Length > 0)
    {
        yield return group.Take(group.Length);
    }
}
```

Because you mention that "processing" of response is also IO operation, then `async/await` approach is most efficient, because it using only one thread and process other tasks when previous tasks waiting for response from web service or from file writing IO operations.

Comment: `Task.Delay(5000)` will make sure that the task will complete after 5 seconds?. What I need is to make sure that only 5 tasks will run in 1 second. And yes the calculation is another async task that will write the output into a text file.

Comment: `Task.Delay(1000)` was added to the collection of tasks, then `Task.WhenAll` will sure that next 5 urls will be processed at least after 1 seconds or when all 5 urls have processed.

Comment: Thanks for the modification, so what is `SplitToGroupsOfFive`

Comment: Added `SplitToGroupsOfFive` method implementation