# Web App, control number of available tasks in Hangifre jobs, each executing Parallel.ForEachAsync

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, semaphore, hangfire, parallel.foreachasync

I'm building an app that will schedule some jobs with Hangfire. They will from time to time execute at the same time. Each jobs has number of "configs" to process. To speed up things it is executing using `Parallel.ForEachAsync`.
I'm looking for a way to control number of threads/tasks that can be used by those `ForEachAsync` calls.

I this I'm going in a wrong direction since `ParallelOptions` are specified once and cannot be adjusted if number of available threads will change.
I was also thinking about `Semaphore` but cannot figure it out.

Maybe a Singleton service registered that would hold info about number of available threads and then each hangfire job would use it to decide how many "configs" it can execute in parallel.

I'm looking for an advice on this, of course code samples are more than welcome.

Comment: Could you provide more details about why configuring the [`ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) property is not sufficient for your case?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. So maybe I do not understand this properly but  I assume that when I hardcode MaxDegreeOfParallelism in both jobs, it can lead to  exceeding number available threads or something like this.
Is Parallel.ForEach without any option specified controlling number of tasks on it's own? So the only thing I should worry about is the memory?

Comment: The `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` sets an upper limit to the degree of parallelism, in other words defines the maximum number of concurrent asynchronous operations. Isn't this what you want? An asynchronous operation is not a thread, and typically [doesn't require a thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) for most of its lifetime.

Comment: So can I assume that if I leave it unlimited in any way, it should still be safe?
Also is number of concurrent operations something that has its limit in terms of available resources of your app?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? Are you worried that your program will crash, or produce incorrect results? If you launch too many asynchronous operations concurrently, you might start getting timeout exceptions because there won't be enough resources (CPU, memory, network bandwidth etc) for all of the operations to complete in a timely manner.

Comment: ah yes that was the answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It has already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290498/how-can-i-limit-parallel-foreach
This question is not related to Hangfire, hence it should be removed from the tags and the title